Dask concat on multiple dataframe axis=1
I am new to Dask. While attempting to run concat on a list of DataFrames, I noticed it is consuming more time, resources, and tasks than expected. Here are the details of my run:
Scheduler (same as client).
Two worker nodes.
I have six parquet partitioned directories, each containing four partitioned files. The output consists of 25 rows and 87,000 columns. Each input folder contains 1-10 rows and 10,000 to 20,000 columns, with every directory being less than 1GB.
Below is the code I executed and logs. Could you please suggest what I might be doing wrong and how I can reduce the time, resources, and steps involved?
Logs:
 UserWarning: Sending large graph of size 11.14 MiB.
This may cause some slowdown.
Consider loading the data with Dask directly
 or using futures or delayed objects to embed the data into the graph without repetition.
See also https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/best-practices.html#load-data-with-dask for more information.
  warnings.warn(
client.py:3371: UserWarning: Sending large graph of size 10.33 MiB.
This may cause some slowdown.
Consider loading the data with Dask directly
 or using futures or delayed objects to embed the data into the graph without repetition.
See also https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/best-practices.html#load-data-with-dask for more information.
  warnings.warn(
Duration at the end 803.7652008533478 seconds
completed writing to file

Dask Dashboard

Dask Dashboard Video
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client
import sys
import os
import glob
import time

# Start the timer
start_time = time.time()

# Connect to the Dask distributed cluster
client = Client('IP:8786')  # Replace with your scheduler address and port

dirs = sys.argv[1]
directory = dirs

# Use a wildcard pattern to get all Parquet file paths in the directory
parquet_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*.parquet'))
print(parquet_files)


df_list = [dd.read_parquet(file) for file in parquet_files]


df_list = [df.set_index('ID') for df in df_list]

df_list = [df.persist() for df in df_list]

concatenated_df = dd.concat(df_list, axis=1)

output_path = 'output.parquet'

# Write the DataFrame to Parquet files in parallel
try:
    concatenated_df.to_parquet(output_path, write_index=True)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error writing Parquet files: {e}")
    raise

# Print duration and close client
end_time = time.time()
print(f"Duration at the end {end_time-start_time} seconds")
print("completed writing to file")


client.close()

Note:
I am starting with small DataFrames, and I understand that using pandas would be faster and easier for these. However, I aim to extend this solution to handle very large DataFrames, so I am testing with small DataFrames initially.
Expectation: Run the code faster and use resources whatever is required and reduce tasks run.

Does the code you provided generate these logs and dashboard? I don't see a good reason in it for the warnings about graph size, and the strange things on the Dashboard.

@GuillaumeEB My code doesn't generate these warnings. Dask generates these warnings
